# Access public field of other module in unity

Tags: c#, reflection, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to read a field from another class library(mod) for Kerbal Space Program. I cannot directly access the field since the compiler is not aware of it and it is of a different namespace.

Here's the source for the field I want access to:

```
namespace ferram4
{
    public class FARControlSys : FARBaseAerodynamics
    {
        public static double termVel;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do such a thing using reflection during run-time?

Comment: The field is public, why can't you access it? What is the error? Is it just because you can't add a reference to the assembly containing the member at build time, and only have it loaded into your address space at runtime? Why can't you add a reference to it?

Comment: Exactly, I can't (as far as I'm aware of) add a reference to the other mod, it is being loaded and used by the Unity engine. And it would be sweet if there was a way to see if the mod is loaded without fiddling with its code and also have my code compile without the need of the other mods DLL or sources!

Comment: How is it not possible for you to `var mydouble = ferram4.FARControlSys.termVel;`?

Comment: Because at compile-time, it sounds like, the assembly containing `ferram4` isn't referenced, so the compiler cannot resolve the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `Type` object representing the type in question using [`GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx) and passing the [assembly-qualified name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname(v=vs.110).aspx) of the type.

Once you have the type, you can call [`GetField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getfield(v=vs.110).aspx) on it to get the field object for the field in question, then you can [get](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) or [set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.setvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) the value of that field with the appropriate methods of `FieldInfo`.

Obviously you'll want to make sure you do all the appropriate null/failure checking to handle cases where the other mod you are poking around in isn't loaded (or to handle the case where the mod eventually changes the name of the member, which could conceivably happen although it's maybe slightly less likely since the field isn't a private implementation detail).

Comment: Wonderful! This did the trick! I had to do some research on assembly-qualified-names, and I ended up downloading a trial of Reflector to find it.